# Sort products by Sale price and stock status

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, meta-query, order, sort, meta-value

I want to sort products by sale price and in stock and regular price at first but doesn't find solution anywhere. Here is what I have implemented and didn't get the solution:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'avs_first_sort_by_stock_amount', 9999 );

function avs_first_sort_by_stock_amount( $args ) {
   if (is_product_category() && !isset( $_GET['orderby'] )) {
       $args = array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    $args[ 'meta_key' ] = '_stock_status',
                    $args[ 'orderby' ] = 'meta_value',
                    $args[ 'order' ] = 'ASC',
                ),                    
                array(
                    $args[ 'meta_key' ] = '_sale_price',
                    $args[ 'orderby' ] = 'meta_value_num',
                    $args[ 'order' ] = 'DESC',
                ),                    
                array(
                    $args[ 'meta_key' ] = '_price',
                    $args[ 'orderby' ] = 'meta_value_num',
                    $args[ 'order' ] = 'DESC',
                )
        )
    ); 

     return $args;
   
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

I followed the WP_Query docs to build this.

```
$args = [
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            '_stock_status' => [
                'key'     => '_stock_status',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ],
            '_sale_price' => [
                'key'     => '_sale_price',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ],
            '_price' => [
                'key'     => '_price',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'orderby' => [
        '_stock_status' => 'ASC',
        '_sale_price'   => 'DESC',
        '_price'        => 'DESC'
    ]
];
```

This will order by stock first, sale price second and price third.

There is no way to order by two or more values simultaneously, at least not that I know of or could find.