# Query order by a numeric ACF field

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I created a query for the custom post type of "departments" the query gets me every department with ACF field "type_of_cetifecate" = "bach" and with a certain category id, until this point everything is working fine, but when I try to sort the query by certain numeric acf fields the query doesn't work, my code so far:

```
$bachelor= new wp_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'departments',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key'       => 'new_price',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'category__and'  => get_field('category_id'),
    'meta_key'       => 'type_of_cetifecate',
    'meta_value'     => 'bach'
));
```

Comment: Welcome! We can't help with code support for third-party plugins (ACF) as it is [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. But there are numerous spelling mistakes in your code. `wp_Query` needs to be `WP_Query`, you have two `meta_key` values, and `type_of_cetifecate` is spelled wrong (but that may be how it's defined in your code, double check that). Here's the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) for `WP_Query`.

Comment: Check this
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/391060/sort-products-by-sale-price-and-stock-status/391093#391093

Comment: you'll need to be more specific than "it doesn't work", e.g. it doesn't work they're in the wrong order, or it doesn't work no posts are found, or it doesn't work the wrong posts are found, etc. Also are you sure the field is numeric and not a structured value? What does the raw value of the post meta look like if you try to `var_dump` it or inspect the database? Also YourManDan is right about ACF being offtopic, if this requires any knowledge of ACF to solve then it cannot be solved here